# Amazon AWS RDS 120GB free storage suddenly became 0GB within less than 2 hours

Tags: amazon-rds, aws

I've been using AWS RDS db.m4.large with 128GB storage for MySQL(InnoDB) for more than one year now.

The size of my database is now less than 2GB and the free storage had always been more than 125GB as captured below but it suddenly dropped to 0GB in less than 2 hours 2 weeks ago.

So I upgraded the storage to 250GB but it was dropped to 0GB again two days ago.

[Free storage suddenly dropped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo8CF.jpg)

So I asked AWS customer center about it and they told me that mysqlInnoDbTablespace took 243GB and I can reduce the size of it by executing OPTIMIZE TABLE on all of my tables.

```
dataVolumeAvailableSize 43.3 gb,
dataVolumeTotalSize 295 gb
dataVolumeUsedSize  251 gb
mysqlErrorLogFileSize   72.4 kb
mysqlGeneralLogBackupSize   0 bytes
mysqlGeneralLogFileSize 0 bytes
mysqlGeneralLogSize 0 bytes
mysqlInnoDbLogSize  256 mb
mysqlInnoDbTablespace   243 gb
mysqlSlowLogBackupSize  124 mb
mysqlSlowLogFileSize    35.9 kb
mysqlSlowLogSize    4.03 gb
```

I did it but the free storage hasn't been increased. so I asked them again but they haven't replied my inquiry.

Below is the size of my database. it's less than 2GB.

[The size of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShyaX.jpg)

Did anybody experience this kind of case or can somebody help me to free up the free storage?

Thanks.